# Replace characters by dictionary using .split() and .join()

Tags: javascript

I tried this code to replace all characters inside text inside text variable but nothing works.

Could you explain what I am doing wrong please?

```js
let text = "anotacia finansur angariSgebaSi asaxuli informacia, mis axsna-ganmartebiT SeniSvnebSi mocemul informaciasTan erTad, momxmarebels saSualebas aZlevs winaswar gansazRvros sawarmos fuladi saxsrebis warmoqmnis realuroba da drouloba. finansuri angariSgeba aseve gviCvenebs sawarmos xelmZRvanelobis mier, maTTvis mindobili resursebis marTvis Sedegebs. sawarmos mogebisa da zaralis angariSgebaSi xarjebis aRiareba xdeba maSin, Tu danaxarjebis gawevisa da Semosavlebis calkeuli muxlebis miRebas Soris arsebobs pirdapiri kavSiri. es aris amonagebis da danaxarjebis Sesabamisobis principi. igi gulisxmobs erTi da igive sameurneo operaciiT, an movleniT gamowveuli xarjebisa da amonagebis erTdroul aRiarebas. standartiT, sawarmom xarjebis klasifikacia unda moaxdinos maTi funqciuri daniSnulebis an ekonomikuri Sinaarsis mixedviT. warmoebis seqtoris sawarmoebma ( mrewveloba, soflis meurneoba, mSenebloba)unda gamoiyenon ekonomikri elementebis mixedviT xarjebis dajgufeba. momsaxurebis sferos sawarmoebma ki SeiZleba xarjebi daajgufon maTi funqciuri daniSnulebis mixedviT. Tu samrewvelo tipis sawarmoebi airCeven mogeba-zaralis angariSgebis wardgenas danaxarjTa funqciuri daniSnulebis meTodis safuZvelze, maSin ganmartebiT SeniSvnebSi unda gaxsnan informacia danaxarjTa elementebis ( masalis xarji, SromiTi xarji, cveTis xarji)";


let ge = ['ა','ბ','გ','დ','ე','ვ','ზ','თ','ი','კ','ლ','მ','ნ','ო','პ','რ','ს','ტ','უ','ფ','ქ','ღ','ყ','შ','ჩ','ც','ძ','წ','ჭ','ხ','ჯ','ჰ'];

let en = ['a','b','g','d','e','v','z','T','i','k','l','m','n','o','p','r','s','t','u','f','q','R','y','S','C','c','Z','w','W','x','j','h'];

replaced = [];
for (var i = 0; i < ge.length; i++) {
    text.split(en[i]).join(ge[i]);
}
console.log(text)
```

Comment: U can not modify text variable, u should create a new one with your result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't assign the new text to your var.
You should replace `text.split(en[i]).join(ge[i]);` by `text = text.split(en[i]).join(ge[i]);`

Answer (score 2):

Can't you use the "replace" method ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

```
for (var i = 0; i < ge.length; i++) {
  text.replace(en[i], ge[i]);
}
```

Comment: No i can't replace method only replaces first character

Comment: @Gurami : you [may use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62491538/11299053) 'g' flag along with RegExp

Answer (score 2):

If replacement by dictionary is what you're attempting to build, there's another way:

```js
const ge = [...'აბგდევზთიკლმნოპრსტუფქღყშჩცძწჭხჯჰ'],
      en = [...'abgdevzTiklmnoprstufqRySCcZwWxjh'],
      text = 'anotacia finansur angariSgebaSi asaxuli informacia'
      
      result = text.replace(
        new RegExp(`${en.join('|')}`, 'g'),
        m => ge[en.indexOf(m)]
      )
        
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

// .join method will return a new string

```
for (var i = 0; i < ge.length; i++) {
    text = text.split(en[i]).join(ge[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows -

```js
let text = "anotacia finansur angariSgebaSi asaxuli informacia, mis axsna-ganmartebiT SeniSvnebSi mocemul informaciasTan erTad, momxmarebels saSualebas aZlevs winaswar gansazRvros sawarmos fuladi saxsrebis warmoqmnis realuroba da drouloba. finansuri angariSgeba aseve gviCvenebs sawarmos xelmZRvanelobis mier, maTTvis mindobili resursebis marTvis Sedegebs. sawarmos mogebisa da zaralis angariSgebaSi xarjebis aRiareba xdeba maSin, Tu danaxarjebis gawevisa da Semosavlebis calkeuli muxlebis miRebas Soris arsebobs pirdapiri kavSiri. es aris amonagebis da danaxarjebis Sesabamisobis principi. igi gulisxmobs erTi da igive sameurneo operaciiT, an movleniT gamowveuli xarjebisa da amonagebis erTdroul aRiarebas. standartiT, sawarmom xarjebis klasifikacia unda moaxdinos maTi funqciuri daniSnulebis an ekonomikuri Sinaarsis mixedviT. warmoebis seqtoris sawarmoebma ( mrewveloba, soflis meurneoba, mSenebloba)unda gamoiyenon ekonomikri elementebis mixedviT xarjebis dajgufeba. momsaxurebis sferos sawarmoebma ki SeiZleba xarjebi daajgufon maTi funqciuri daniSnulebis mixedviT. Tu samrewvelo tipis sawarmoebi airCeven mogeba-zaralis angariSgebis wardgenas danaxarjTa funqciuri daniSnulebis meTodis safuZvelze, maSin ganmartebiT SeniSvnebSi unda gaxsnan informacia danaxarjTa elementebis ( masalis xarji, SromiTi xarji, cveTis xarji) Sesaxeb.anotacia finansur angariSgebaSi asaxuli informacia, mis axsna-ganmartebiT SeniSvnebSi mocemul informaciasTan erTad, momxmarebels saSualebas aZlevs winaswar gansazRvros sawarmos fuladi saxsrebis warmoqmnis realuroba da drouloba. finansuri angariSgeba aseve gviCvenebs sawarmos xelmZRvanelobis mier, maTTvis mindobili resursebis marTvis Sedegebs. sawarmos mogebisa da zaralis angariSgebaSi xarjebis aRiareba xdeba maSin, Tu danaxarjebis gawevisa da Semosavlebis calkeuli muxlebis miRebas Soris arsebobs pirdapiri kavSiri. es aris amonagebis da danaxarjebis Sesabamisobis principi. igi gulisxmobs erTi da igive sameurneo operaciiT, an movleniT gamowveuli xarjebisa da amonagebis erTdroul aRiarebas. standartiT, sawarmom xarjebis klasifikacia unda moaxdinos maTi funqciuri daniSnulebis an ekonomikuri Sinaarsis mixedviT. warmoebis seqtoris sawarmoebma ( mrewveloba, soflis meurneoba, mSenebloba)unda gamoiyenon ekonomikri elementebis mixedviT xarjebis dajgufeba. momsaxurebis sferos sawarmoebma ki SeiZleba xarjebi daajgufon maTi funqciuri daniSnulebis mixedviT. Tu samrewvelo tipis sawarmoebi airCeven mogeba-zaralis angariSgebis wardgenas danaxarjTa funqciuri daniSnulebis meTodis safuZvelze, maSin ganmartebiT SeniSvnebSi unda gaxsnan informacia danaxarjTa elementebis ( masalis xarji, SromiTi xarji, cveTis xarji) Sesaxeb.";


let ge = ['ა','ბ','გ','დ','ე','ვ','ზ','თ','ი','კ','ლ','მ','ნ','ო','პ','რ','ს','ტ','უ','ფ','ქ','ღ','ყ','შ','ჩ','ც','ძ','წ','ჭ','ხ','ჯ','ჰ'];

let en = ['a','b','g','d','e','v','z','T','i','k','l','m','n','o','p','r','s','t','u','f','q','R','y','S','C','c','Z','w','W','x','j','h'];

//console.log(text);


for (var i = 0; i < ge.length; i++) {
    
    text = text.split(en[i]).join(ge[i]);
    
    /*
    // Another alternative 1 -
    // Using regex to replace all occurences of en[i] to ge[i]
    var re = new RegExp(en[i], 'g');
    text = text.replace(re,ge[i]);
    */
    /*
    // Another alternative 2 -
    text = text.replaceAll(en[i],ge[i])
    */
}



console.log(text)
```